# Unicode combining characters: Visual Studio versus Wikipedia versus Firefox - who's right?

Tags: unicode

Wikipedia [has an image](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datei:Composicion_nh.svg) explaining how Unicode composition works. It says that ñ can be combined from n and ~ like this:

[image: Wikipedia combining n]

In [another example](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:U_niesk%C5%82adovaje_Unicode.svg) it also has the accent after the character.

[image: Wikipedia combining y]

However, when I do that in Visual Studio (C++), the U+0303 character puts the tilde on the following character:

```cpp
int main()
{
    auto n1 = "ñ";  // U+00F1
    auto n2 = "◌̃n"; // U+0303 in front of n
    auto n3 = "n◌̃"; // U+0303 behind n
}
```

<sub>And Firefox for Stack Overflow, too, as it seems.</sub>

Here's how it looks in my Visual Studio 2022:

[image: Visual Studio screenshot]

In [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character), Wikipedia explicitly states

> In Unicode, diacritics are always added after the main character

So, who's right, and why?

Comment: UNICODE source: [UAX 15 - Unicode Normalization Forms](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr15/)

Comment: Your `n2` and `n3` examples contain three characters: there's an additional U+25CC DOTTED CIRCLE before the combining tilde; this may explain the misplacement. In any case, code editors aren't necessarily very good at rendering typographically challenging stuff like combining diacritics. Some coders might even prefer to see a distinction between the composed character and the combining sequence.

Comment: @lenz: OMG. I didn't notice that the circle is its own character. Do you want to post this as an answer?